# Indexing very large csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv, indexing

I feel like this is a very stupid question, but I'm unable to think about the problem anymore.

I have a very large amount of data (60+GB) in csv format ordered by id:

```
id, "{data}"
id2, "{data}"
...
```

I have another set of data that needs to be combined with this data in a dictionary format (currently split up over some pickled files):

```
{player_id: {rating, [ids]}, player_id2: {rating, [ids]}, ... }
```

Where the ids in the csv data correspond to ids in the lists above. I'd like to put the details for each id into this data from the csv data, meaning I have to take an id, hunt for it in the csv data, and then write it to this dictionary format. The big bottleneck here is therefore looking up the data in the csv files by id and reading it from disk.

My current solution is to split up the csv data into many small files (1-2mb) and index which files contain which ids, so that searching for the data is a lot quicker than parsing the entire csv data, but is still not constant, and still requires opening a csv file at every step.

Is there a quicker way to do this? I feel like I'm being very silly and there is a faster way, as my solution with multiprocessing is still going to take in the area of 2 weeks to finish.

Happy to clarify if my question is unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Using CSV for 60GB of data is not a good idea for precisely the reasons you are finding here. Is it possible to move it into a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database?

Comment: are the ids always sequential? (1,2,...,N) ? and  you are just trying to find one(with id X?)

Comment: May be try pandas pandas.pydata.org

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_row(id):
    with open("fname.csv") as f:
        row = next(itertools.islice(f,id-1,id),None)   
    return row
```

its still going to be painfully slow ... you should  think about using a database ... or at the very least storing the data as fixed width entries (ie always 37 bytes per row), if you store fixed width entries you can calculate an offset `offset = id*37;f.seek(offset);return f.read(37)` and that should be ~ roughly constant time ...

Comment: Is there a particular type of database with python api that has fast access time? The biggest bottleneck is definitely i/o even with constant lookup.

Comment: assuming you are querying against an indexed field it should be near constant lookup time ... and access time ... in pretty much any sql ... Im less versed with nosql but i understand nosql is easily parallelized for searches